# How to change my URL structure on dynamic selection ID which is retrieving from database

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to change my URL structure, Instead of showing ID it should show full name and remove .php from end.

```
http://example.com/index.php?catid=5
```

This should convert into

```
http://example.com/MDM
```

Here **MDM** is category name which is retriving from database.

Is there any help I can get on this.

Comment: What OS are your running, which server are you using, are you using any specific framework?

Comment: There are so many questions about this on the website which are far more concrete than yours. Yours is hard to answer because you only say what you want and in a way that expects anyone else to read your brainwaives to find what actually your setup is. A search for "pretty urls" combine with your setup might bring you a bit further:http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+pretty+urls - In the end it is normally reading how to configure your webserver.

Comment: Windows 10 OS, Apache server, using only core php

Comment: Hi hakre, I am new to this, Just want to know is there any way possible by using htaccess I can change my URL structure or any other way possible.

Comment: I mark this aas a duplicate as we have so endless many of these on the site, the fallack resource presented as an answer to your question is the more modern pattern and similar to what suggested in the linked duplicate.

Comment: Hi RiDev, yes there is. The Apache module for that is called Mod_Rewrite, it's fully documented in the Apache documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/ - If you wonder about how data flows into your PHP script, that is covered in the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php and http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Hi hakre, I am learning php after serach in google and stackoverflow I posted this question and hope someone will replay with  more clarification but you marked it as duplicate so I am not able to get any related answer .and your reference is not what I am searching **htaccess rewrite on urls without common pattern**. Anyway thank you for your help. If possible remove duplicate mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can essentially do this 2 ways:

### The .htaccess route with mod_rewrite

Add a file called `.htaccess` in your root folder, and add something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?Some-text-goes-here/([0-9]+)$ /picture.php?id=$1
```

This will tell Apache to enable mod_rewrite for this folder, and if it gets asked a URL matching the regular expression it rewrites it *internally* to what you want, without the end user seeing it. Easy, but inflexible, so if you need more power:

### The PHP route

Put the following in your .htaccess instead:

```
FallbackResource index.php
```

This will tell it to run your `index.php` for all files it cannot normally find in your site. In there you can then for example:

```
$path = ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');    // Trim leading slash(es)
$elements = explode('/', $path);                // Split path on slashes
if(empty($elements[0])) {                       // No path elements means home
    ShowHomepage();
} else switch(array_shift($elements))             // Pop off first item and switch
{
    case 'Some-text-goes-here':
        ShowPicture($elements); // passes rest of parameters to internal function
        break;
    case 'more':
        ...
    default:
        header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
        Show404Error();
}
```

This is how big sites and CMS-systems do it, because it allows far more flexibility in parsing URLs, config and database dependent URLs etc. For sporadic usage the hardcoded rewrite rules in `.htaccess` will do fine though.